# Search and replace with user decision in Microsoft Word with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am still quite new to writing VBA code, but I would like to solve the following problem:

With the help of the macro recorder I could already solve part of my problem. I can search for different texts, and replace **ALL** of them.
However, I would like to search for text in my WORD document, and let the user decide if he wants to change this text or not.
Here is an example: I want to search for "m2" and change the text to "m²". But it is also possible that "m2" is part of an article number or something similar, so that no changes may be made here.

But my GOOGLE search does not return any results, because searching for "search" does not offer a way out

My code for the first part looks like this:

```
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .text = "m2"
    .replacement.text = "m²"
    Forward = True
    .wrap = wdFindContinue
    .format = False
    MatchCase = True
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

I then have several dozen of these in my VBA code, one after the other.

I am very happy about any help.

Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
Sub Demo()
Dim StrFnd As String, StrRep As String, Rslt
StrFnd = InputBox("Find Text")
StrRep = InputBox("Replacement Text")
With ActiveDocument.Range
    With .Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Replacement.ClearFormatting
      .Text = StrFnd
      .Replacement.Text = ""
      .MatchWholeWord = True
      .Forward = True
      .Format = False
      .MatchCase = True
      .Wrap = wdFindStop
      .Execute
    End With
    'Replace the found text, asking first
    Do While .Find.Found
      .Duplicate.Select
      Rslt = MsgBox("Replace this instance of:" & vbCr & _
        StrFnd & vbCr & "with:" & vbCr & _
        StrRep, vbYesNoCancel)
      If Rslt = vbCancel Then Exit Sub
      If Rslt = vbYes Then .Text = StrRep
      .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
      .Find.Execute
    Loop
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: One more thing.

If I want to search and replace using wild cards, I have a problem:
I search for ([a-z])-([a-z]) to find false separations and replace them with \1\2. Finding works fine, but replacing gives "\1\2" in the text.
.MatchWildcards = True 
I have added in the code.

Comment: @Melpro: that's another question. Perhaps better to research it yourself, see how far you get, then post another question with whatever code you have. e.g. you could consider (a) how you can get the text that Word is about to replace, (b) how you get the text that Word is going to replace it with and (c) how you present all of that to your user.

Answer (score 0):

Is it enough for you?

```
Private Sub ChangeTextWithAsking()
    Dim res As VbMsgBoxResult
    Selection.Find.Execute FindText:="m2"
    Do While Selection.Find.Found
        res = MsgBox("Change?", vbYesNoCancel)
        Select Case res
            Case vbYes
                Selection.Delete
                Selection.TypeText "m"
                Selection.Font.Superscript = True
                Selection.TypeText "2"
            Case vbNo
                Selection.MoveRight
        Case Else
            Exit Do
        End Select
        Selection.Find.Execute
    Loop
End Sub
```